# shoreditch: no option to enable on /civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1

Tags: shoreditch

So I installed shoreditch on a drupal 7 civicrm. I can enable on the extensions page but on /civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1 I see no option to enable the shoreditch them. 
I can add the custom-civicrm.css there but not the shoreditch option I see on another (Wordpress) installation. 
This is on a civicrm 5.6.0. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you cleared CiviCRM caches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequent reason for that error: Double-check, that your URL resource entries are correct! At best, you should use the URL variables, such as e.g.:

[civicrm.files]/extensions

Comment: (shame on me) Thank you Detlev for pointing me in that direction

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal, install the Shoredich theme extension. Make sure you use the latest one! Check the extension documentation.

Basically in Drupal you choose the Seven theme as the CiviCRM admin theme.

/admin/appearance

Then, back over in CiviCRM in Resource URLs, you set the CSS to use the Shoreditch CSS.

/civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1

Should then work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Had that once before, as @Laryn mentioned clearing my caches helped!

Comment: I cleared drupal cache, cleaned cache on /civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1,  I rebuilt the menu on civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1, I removed everything from sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c... no luck

Comment: It worked for me.....sorry I can not help you. Hope someone else has another idea.

Comment: other people have it working with civicrm 5.6.0?